# How to make an Alert dialog in full screen in Android?

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-alertdialog

How to make an Alert Dialog in full screen in Android?

Comment: This is not a way to ask question on StackOverflow. Provide what you have worked on, any tutorial or your code snippet.

Answer (score 30):

Try below code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Comment: It works, but this also changes the theme.

Comment: Or with a white background you can use `android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen` or `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen`

Answer (score 17):

you must create a custom style for your dialog

in your style.xml

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>   
    <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

while inflating your dialog set this theme

`dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);`

Comment: This also changes the dialog style.

Answer (score 15):

【Method 1 | Use Custom Style】

In styles file:

```
<style name="myFullscreenAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">      //no actionbar, but status bar exists
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>                       //remove status bar
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>        //smooth animation
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>                      //change button text color
</style>
```

In java file:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.myFullscreenAlertDialogStyle);   //second argument
```

---

【Method 2 | Use Built-In Style】

In java file:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
```

- This method will make the button text become green color, you can use `dialog.getButton().setTextColor()` to change it.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using DialogFragment to build AlertDialog you may set MATCH_PARENT on LayoutParams in onResume():

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
}
```

Comment: While this does work, the vie winside it doesn't go with MATCH_PARENT