# How to make a custom alertdialog fullscreen

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I wish to make a custom `AlertDialog` full screen like a new activity screen.

Tried these answers and still not working

- [Android make a dialog appear in fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315343/android-make-a-dialog-appear-in-fullscreen)
- [Make AlertDialog Custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514267/make-alertdialog-custom)
- [How to make an Alert dialog in full screen in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544436/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-in-full-screen-in-android)

```java
public void newDialog(final Context c){

    final AlertDialog alertDialog;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    dialogueView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialogue, null);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogueView);

    alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    dialogueView.findViewById((R.id.closeBtn)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

layout_dialogue.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
style="@style/full_screen_dialog"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/frame">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/closeBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_sky"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

style.xml

```xml
<style name="full_screen_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

I had also tried

```java
android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen  

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

None of them are working for me. Any suggestion on how to accomplished it?

Comment: I think as per your requirements you need to use Dialog instead of Alert Dialog. Dialog provide you to use your own custom view.

Comment: Yes, I can actually achieve it through Dialog, but can it be done using AlertDialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use custom style let me show you an example

**style.xml**

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

**Activity.java**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this , R.style.DialogTheme)
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, but how can i use my custom layout with specific button?

Comment: your can use custom layout example
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this ,R.style.DialogTheme)
dialog.setCustomLayout(R.layout.alert_Layout)

Comment: yep, that's a workable way. But, i am trying to do it with alertdialog instead of dialog. Is this possible?

Comment: works better with name="android:windowIsFloating">true. 
Good ans tho. Thanks.

Comment: This show black spots at the top and bottom of the dialog

Answer (score 4):

You can use following methodology. (It is defined in Kotlin but you can implement for Java as well)

```
class FullscreenDialog: DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_no_internet, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        if(dialog != null) {
            val width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            dialog.window?.setLayout(width, height)
        }
    }

}
```

**Add following to your styles.xml**

```
<style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/appPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/appPrimaryColor</item>

    <!-- Set this to true if you want Full Screen without status bar -->
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>

    <!-- This is important! Don't forget to set window background -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>

</style>
```

**To show dialog use following:**

```
val fullScreenDialog = FullscreenDialog()
fullScreenDialog.isCancelable = false
fullScreenDialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "MyTag")
```

Answer (score 0):

What i have been using for fullscreen dialog with no margin

```
public class ShareImageEditorDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL,
                android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_share_image, container);

        return v;
    }
}
```

and to show on button click

```
new ShareImageEditorDialog().show(((FragmentActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyTag");
```